Flutter: how to make the "DotsIndicator" on the screen move from top to bottom?
I had a case where I was asked to change the position of "DotsIndicator" on my on_boarding page in an application I made with Flutter. I tried various ways to match the design.
This my code
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

// another import

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class WalkthroughPage extends StatefulWidget {
  WalkthroughPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  SharedPreferences prefs = serviceLocator.get<SharedPreferences>();

  @override
  _WalkthroughPageState createState() => _WalkthroughPageState();
}

class _WalkthroughPageState extends State<WalkthroughPage> {
  final introKey = GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState>();
  bool lastPage = false;
  double pageposition = 0;

  void _onIntroEnd(context) {
    _setPreference();
    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(ShowLogin());
  }

  void _nextPage() {
    introKey.currentState!.controller
        .nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  Widget _buildImage(String assetName, [double width = 350]) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/$assetName', width: width),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _setPreference() async {
    await widget.prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    const pageDecoration = const PageDecoration(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
      bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0),
      imagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 40,
      ),
      bodyTextStyle:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
    );

    var introList = [
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk1.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Food ESTE ! Ready to roll",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                  "Digitalisasi Food ESTE !",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 65)),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _nextPage();
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: KmpFlatButton(
                    minWidth: 230,
                    onPressed: (){ 
                      _nextPage();
                    }, 
                    buttonType: ButtonType.secondary, 
                    title: "Mulai",
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk2.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Branding Food ESTE",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                  "Food ESTE For Future",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 65)),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _nextPage();
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Container(
                  child: KmpFlatButton(
                    minWidth: 230,
                    onPressed: (){ 
                      _nextPage();
                    }, 
                    buttonType: ButtonType.secondary, 
                    title: "Mulai",
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk3.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Pembinaan Food ESTE",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                  "Food ESTE Quick",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 30)),
            KmpFlatButton(
              minWidth: 230,
              buttonType: ButtonType.secondary,
              onPressed: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
              title: 'Mulai',
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
    ];
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: IntroductionScreen(
            globalBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            onChange: (page) {
              pageposition = page.toDouble();
              setState(() {});
              if (page == introList.length - 1) {
                setState(() {
                  lastPage = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  lastPage = false;
                });
              }
            },
            key: introKey,
            globalHeader: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    DotsIndicator(
                      position: pageposition.toInt(),
                      dotsCount: introList.length,
                      decorator: DotsDecorator(
                        size: Size(10.0, 10.0),
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        activeColor: Colors.black,
                        activeSize: Size(21.0, 10.0),
                        activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            pages: introList,
            onDone: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
            showNextButton: false,
            showDoneButton: false,
            isProgress: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


and this is the result of my code after I run it

and this is the design of the screen that I want

can anyone help me to make the "DotsIndicator" to the position as in the design?

Change globalHeader to dotsDecorator and dotsContainerDecorator to show an indicator with desired theme.
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

// another import

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class WalkthroughPage extends StatefulWidget {
  WalkthroughPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  SharedPreferences prefs = serviceLocator.get<SharedPreferences>();

  @override
  _WalkthroughPageState createState() => _WalkthroughPageState();
}

class _WalkthroughPageState extends State<WalkthroughPage> {
  final introKey = GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState>();
  bool lastPage = false;
  double pageposition = 0;

  void _onIntroEnd(context) {
    _setPreference();
    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(ShowLogin());
  }

  void _nextPage() {
    introKey.currentState!.controller
        .nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  Widget _buildImage(String assetName, [double width = 350]) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/$assetName', width: width),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _setPreference() async {
    await widget.prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    const pageDecoration = const PageDecoration(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
      bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0),
      imagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 40,
      ),
      bodyTextStyle:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
    );

    var introList = [
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk1.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Food ESTE ! Ready to roll",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Digitalisasi Food ESTE !",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 65)),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _nextPage();
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: KmpFlatButton(
                    minWidth: 230,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _nextPage();
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.secondary,
                    title: "Mulai",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk2.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Branding Food ESTE",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Food ESTE For Future",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 65)),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _nextPage();
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Container(
                  child: KmpFlatButton(
                    minWidth: 230,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _nextPage();
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.secondary,
                    title: "Mulai",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
      PageViewModel(
        image: _buildImage("walk3.png"),
        titleWidget: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Pembinaan Food ESTE",
              textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextPalette.registerTitleStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bodyWidget: Container(
          height: Screen(size).hp(68),
          child: Column(children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Food ESTE Quick",
                  textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextPalette.registerSubtitleStyle),
            ),
            Flexible(child: SizedBox(height: 30)),
            KmpFlatButton(
              minWidth: 230,
              buttonType: ButtonType.secondary,
              onPressed: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
              title: 'Mulai',
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        decoration: pageDecoration,
      ),
    ];
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white])),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: IntroductionScreen(
            globalBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            onChange: (page) {
              pageposition = page.toDouble();
              setState(() {});
              if (page == introList.length - 1) {
                setState(() {
                  lastPage = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  lastPage = false;
                });
              }
            },
            key: introKey,
            dotsDecorator: const DotsDecorator(
              size: Size(10.0, 10.0),
              color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
              activeSize: Size(22.0, 10.0),
              activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
              ),
            ),
            dotsContainerDecorator: const ShapeDecoration(
              color: Colors.black87,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
              ),
            ),
            pages: introList,
            onDone: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
            showNextButton: false,
            showDoneButton: false,
            isProgress: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



aku mengubah dari "globalHeader" dengan "globalFooter" dotsDecorator berhasil pindah menjadi di posisi footer tapi bagaimana cara menambahkan dotsDecorator di atas "InkWell" atau bisa diakatakan dotsDecorator posisinya diatas Button("KmpFlatButton")

Hi @UjangAripin, please follow provided code sample it'll work for you, if it's working as expected please accept the answer.
